# Asp.net sitemap node navigation does not cause postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, sitemap

**Working principle**

I have two pages PageA.aspx and PageB.aspx and also a dashboard.aspx. From dashboard, we can access PageA and PageB. When navigating back to dashboard from these pages, we use sitemap nodes.

PageA sitemap is 'Dashboard > PageA' and for PageB it is 'Dashboard > PageB'. I click on Dashboard to navigate to dashboard.aspx

**Condition**

In PageA.aspx I have a radio button (x and y) and a Submit button. My condition is that when I select y radio button and click on submit, I should be redirected to PageB.aspx and the sitemap node in PageB.aspx should be renamed to 'Dashboard > ConditionX'. But if I am navigating directly from dashboard.aspx to PageB.aspx then the site map node should be as 'Dashboard > PageB'.

**What I have done so far**

In PageA.aspx submit click, I check the radio button selection and set a session `Session["IsCondition"]=true` and then use `Response.Redirect("~/PageB.aspx")` to navigate to PageB.aspx.

In `Page_Load()` of PageB.aspx I check the session

```
if (Session["IsCondition"] != null && Convert.ToBoolean(Session["IsCondition"]))
                    {
                       //My code here if condition is satisfied
                        SiteMap.Provider.CurrentNode.ReadOnly = false;
                        SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title = "ConditionX";
                        SiteMap.Provider.CurrentNode.ReadOnly = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //My code here if I was directly accessing from Dashboard
                        SiteMap.Provider.CurrentNode.ReadOnly = false;
                        SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title = "PageB";
                        SiteMap.Provider.CurrentNode.ReadOnly = true;
                    }
```

Moreover, in dashboard.aspx `Page_Load()` I have set `Session["IsCondition"]=null`

**Problem**

When I use the submit button from PageA.aspx to redirect to PageB.aspx then the conditional working is correct in PageB.aspx and the sitemap is shown as 'Dashboard > ConditionX'. From this page,  if I click on Dashboard node in site map, `Page_Load` of dashboard.aspx page is not fired even though I am navigated to Dashboard. Since the Session value is not getting cleared from Dashboard page, clicking on PageB.aspx will load PageB with the condition which is not what I want

**Question**

Why is the dashboard not getting fired?
What am I doing wrong?
Is the dashboard page being cached and shown for which the Page_load isn't getting fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response.Cache.SetNoStore()` in the master page `Page_Load()` solved the problem